# customising the names and number of columns in flexbox grid

Tags: grid, flexbox

Hey guys i am new to [***Flexbox Grid***](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

My Question is that is it possible to change the number of columns in this grid system and the names of columns like `column-6-lap`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can on that.
you can do that in Bourbon Neat but not in this one.